# Creating a circle around trash-o icon in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

How to create a circle around this icon.please give suggestion to me..how to add the circle.

Now my icon like this.[image]

How to create a circle like this[image]

```
<Animated.View
  ref={view => view && (this.iconRef = view._component)}
  onLayout={() =>
    this.iconRef &&
    this.iconRef.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) =>
      this.props.onMeasure({
        x: pageX,
        y: pageY,
        width,
        height,
      })
    )
  }
  style={[
    styles.iconContainer,
    {
      opacity: this.props.opacity,
      transform: [
        {
          scale: Animated.multiply(
            this.props.opacity.interpolate({
              inputRange: [0, 1],
              outputRange: [0.5, 1],
            }),
            this.props.scale
          ),
        },
      ],
    },
  ]}
>
  <Icon name="trash-o" color="white" style={styles.icon} />
</Animated.View>
```

Comment: Use a container with `border-radius: 50%;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
<View style={styles.iconWrapper}>
   <Icon name="trash-o" color="white" style={styles.icon} />
</View>
```

`iconWrapper` style

```
iconWrapper: {
 width: 30,
 borderRadius: 15,
 backgroundColor: 'black',
 padding: 10
}
```

Comment: Actually, [`borderRadius`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view-style-props#borderradius) only support numbers, so '50%' throws an error (`JSON value '50%' of type NSString cannot be converted to NSNumber`), at least on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Add the property `borderRadius: 100` to it's container, just like

```
<View style={{borderRadius: 100}}>
  <Icon name="trash-o" color="white" style={styles.icon} />
</View>
```

---

NOTE: `borderRadius` value is proportional to your container's size.